# Django save chunked files leading to invalid file errors

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

In my create post endpoint I call this function to upload a file (currently for debugging purposes I instantly run assemble_attachment, but when all bugs are fixed, it will run as an automated task)

```py
def _save_chunk(chunk: bytes, chunk_index, attachment_type: str, attachment_name: str, attachment_extension: str):
    if attachment_type == "VIDEO":
        destination = config.media_source + f'temporary/{attachment_name}_{chunk_index}.webm'

        with open(destination, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(chunk)

        return
    
    if attachment_type == "IMAGE":
        destination = config.media_source + f'temporary/{attachment_name}_{chunk_index}.webp'

        with open(destination, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(chunk)

        return
    
    if attachment_type == "AUDIO":
        destination = config.media_source + f'temporary/{attachment_name}_{chunk_index}.{attachment_extension}'

        with open(destination, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(chunk)

        return

def upload_attachment(attachment: UploadedFile, user_permissions: permissions.Permissions) -> tuple:
    # more code

    chunk_index = 1

    for chunk in attachment.chunks():
        _save_chunk(chunk, chunk_index, post_type, attachment_name, attachment_extension)

        chunk_index += 1

    print(f'Chunks saved in {time.time() - start_time} seconds.')

    post_attachment = models.PostAttachment.objects.create(
        attachment_type=post_type,
        name=attachment_name,
        extension=attachment_extension
    )

    assemble_attachments._assemble_attachment(post_attachment)

    # more code
```

For this example, I am showing the flow for saving an image, but the others aren't unstable.
The issue is that some files will give an error, while others will work flawlessly.

```py
def _assemble_image(post_attachment: models.PostAttachment):
    destination = os.path.join(config.media_source, 'attachments', f'{post_attachment.name}.webp')

    image_chunks = []

    for file in os.listdir(config.media_source + 'temporary/'):
        if file.startswith(post_attachment.name):
            chunk_path = os.path.join(config.media_source, 'temporary', file)

            try:
                with open(chunk_path, 'rb') as chunk_file:
                    data = chunk_file.read()
                    if data:
                        image_chunks.append(data)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error reading image chunk {chunk_path}: {e}")

            try:
                os.remove(chunk_path)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                pass

    try:
        if image_chunks:
            image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(b"".join(image_chunks)))

            if _is_animated(image):
                _process_frames(image, destination)
            else:
                image = ImageOps.exif_transpose(image)
                image.save(destination, format="WEBP", save_all=True)

            post_attachment.state = "assembled"
            post_attachment.save()

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing image chunks: {e}")

    return

def _assemble_attachment(post_attachment: models.PostAttachment):
    if post_attachment.attachment_type == "IMAGE":
        return _assemble_image(post_attachment)
        
    if post_attachment.attachment_type == "VIDEO":
        return _assemble_video(post_attachment)
    
    if post_attachment.attachment_type == "AUDIO":
        return _assemble_audio(post_attachment)
```

The error:

```py
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f3e7e52e660>
```

I know the image isn't the issue as I have it saved on my disk and checking it has no problems. I can also see the image preview on the front-end side of the application. For testing, I have also used an image process function that didn't chunk and directly loaded the image into PIL, which also works flawlessly.

```py
def upload_attachment(attachment: UploadedFile, user_permissions: permissions.Permissions) -> tuple:
    # more code

    attachment_name = f"AT_{snowflakes.SnowflakeGenerator().generate_id}.webp"

    img = Image.open(attachment)

    if is_animated_image(img):
        # more code

    else:
        img = ImageOps.exif_transpose(img)

        img.save(f'{config.media_source}attachments/{attachment_name}', format='webp', save_all=True)

    # more code
```